# Can I set a max zoom for a search in CartoDB.js

Tags: javascript, carto, zoom, search

I made a map with a search box that is related to a country. Entering a postal code will zoom completly in to the asked postal code. I would like to center the map to this asked postal code, but not to zoom further in.

I saw several example maps with a maxZoom. Therefore I tried to set maxZoom in CartoDB.js. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? You can see html so far [here](http://jsbin.com/difujozuwo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a valid callback for the onDone, as it doesn't contain the vis object, so the maxZoom setting is not really being applied because the object to apply it is not there. :-)

You can use:

```
  .on('done', function(vis, layers) {
```

instead.